# file chooser in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am trying to make an application that open different office document for iphone.
Iam new to IOS development. I want to ask if there is something similar to file chooser dialog box as one get open when we click open file on our desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you have to fetch the files in a folder using `NSFileManager` and fill a `UITableView`. You can for instance use `-contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`. See more in the [NSFileManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Some code:

```
//  Getting Files at "directory"
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *files = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error];

//  Iterating through files looking for certain file extensions
//  _fileTypes_ is an array of extensions, e.g. [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"txt"];
    for (NSString *fileName in files) 
    {
        if ([_fileTypes_ containsObject:[fileName.pathExtension lowercaseString]]) 
        {
            // Do something with fileName, e.g. adding it to an array and showing it lager in a UITableView
        }
    }
```

Comment: Furthermore, you may want to consider your UX and UI carefully. File choosers are really not the best experience, and if you can avoid them your users will (subconsciously) thank you.

Comment: You should give a serious read to the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) / User Experience Guidelines / Downplay File-Handling Operations